# Passing Environment Variables When Testing in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to pass an environment variable to my app when testing. I have already setup the environment variable as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

When I run my Test (UITests) I try to access the variable in the actual app WeatherApp using the following code:

```
print(ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["TARGET"])
```

But it always prints out nil. What am I missing?

Here is the code in my actual app:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    print(ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["TARGET"]) 


    return true
}
```

Comment: where in the tests have you written print(ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["TARGET"]) It should be written under YourUITestClass: XCTestCase and with some func testExample()

Comment: I updated the code. I don't want to access TARGET value inside my test, I want to access it inside my actual app.

Comment: @pkamb Thank you so much! Yes that helped and solved my issue.